# Xamarin failed to resolve system.security.cryptography?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, system

How would I solve this in Xamarin:

> Failed to resolve
>   System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider reference
>   from System.Core, Version 4.0.0, Culture=Neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" (MT2002)

I am finding great difficulty with this problem as it has popped out of nowhere when running my solution on a real device rather than on a simulator.I would greatly appreciate any help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xamarin: Failed to resolve assembly: System.Security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254480/xamarin-failed-to-resolve-assembly-system-security)

Answer (score 4):

Xamarin.iOS ships `System.Core, Version 2.1.0, ...` (even if it includes newer API that what shipped with 2.1 / Silverlight).

The error above mention `System.Core, Version 4.0.0, ...` and that is not an assembly that ships with Xamarin.iOS, nor is it part of a PCL profile that is supported.

This generally happens because some of your **binaries** are compiled against the *desktop* MS .NET framework. Doing so can include type/member references to things that does not exists in the version shipped by Xamarin.

The solution is to rebuild such binaries against the SDK that ships with Xamarin.iOS or against one of the PCL profiles that it supports.

Note that setting the linker to "Don't link" only hides the error (at build time) and can get you with errors, leading to crash, at runtime (generally a bad trade off).

Comment: System.Core, Version 4.0.0 appears in my core project, if this has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: So to rebuild the binary I would have to add a reference to System.Core, Version 2.1.0 in my core project?

Comment: If you rebuild your code against the Xamarin SDK then you'll be referencing the _right_ (2.1) System.Core assembly. If you rebuild it against a PCL refer to the documentation to pick a compatible profile.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed It! All I had to to was change the build setting to "Don't Link".

Comment: That's not a correct fix and it will cause you other issues.